# Adding fields in ArcMap to enable entering of range numbers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table

I'm trying to enter range numbers such as 1 - 5 , 4- 40, etc in an attribute table for one of my shapefiles as I'm trying to display the depth ranges of different areas around my study area with different colours. But I'm not sure what 'Type' to choose from when adding fields or if this is even the right way to display this type of data. I'm only trying to input the numbers, not the words such as 'Shallow' etc that come with it.

[image: the water depth data]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Never ever put more than one value into a single field as this would only be possible in text fields. Also you would always have trouble to disentagle your text for calculations.

It is way easier to just create two fields for min and max value. From these you can calculate any values needed in a new field later on (like mean or range).

When using these values for labels you can concatenate the both fields quite easily. For example `[min] & " - " & [max] & " m"` will show you the lables like in your screenshot of your original table (used the vbscribt parser here, which is the standard one for label expressions"

Comment: Thanks for that advice. I'm still very new the GIS, so how would I calculate range after making min and max fields? I've done so but after making a new field called 'waterD_range' and with Short integer as type, how do I now calculate the range?

Comment: Right click on the new field header and choose calculate field.

Comment: @DavidJrGbadago You want **two** new fields here, not just one.  One for the `min` value and one for the `max` value.  To do it in a single field it would need to be a text field, and you're going to have a lot of difficulty trying to calculate/report much of value if you store your ranges in a single text field.

Comment: Yes, I did create two fields, min and max but I just don't know how to use the field calculator to calculate the range.